# Debugging application built with mixed ASP.NET versions

Tags: asp.net, debugging, versions, mixed

I am working on an application built using ASP.NET 1.1 but that invokes services built in ASP.NET 2.0.

Attempts to debug my code by setting a breakpoint and attaching the w3wp.exe process fail because IIS is running under ASP.NET 2.0.

If I select ASP.NET 1.1 as the version in IIS then debugging works, but the calls to the 2.0 services (which are everywhere) causes the page to crash.

Does anyone have a solution/workaround to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

.NET 1.1 and 2.0 can't live both in the same process, so you must separate them.

Since you're speaking about w3wp.exe, it seems you're using Windows 2003 Server, which will make things easier.

Make sure there are two application pools on your server.
Put your 1.1 app in one pool, and the 2.0 web service in the other.

It will create two process, and you can debug them separately

Comment: Hi Johan, thanks for the speedy reply! Once I have a better idea how this is done I will give it a try.